# Change spam haiku message

Tags: feature-request, spam, haiku

There have been [far too many questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=haiku) about the infamous spam haiku page.

I am suggesting this page be changed to a more informative message.

Yes, I think it's cute, too. However, too many real users are getting this message. They come here to meta and ask ["wtf!?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/wtf-is-this-got-when-trying-to-answer-a-question-closed). If the message they saw actually explained what was going on, things would be just a tad easier for everyone involved.

> *My dear spam haiku*
>   *You bring both joy and sorrow*
>   *Now please go away*

Comment: WTF this is? / The reasons seem well-hidden / Think about your deed

Comment: @balpha that's not a haiku if you actually pronounce it "double-u tee eff" :)

Comment: @Kip: I know, but we all know what it means, don't we? You know we're not allowed to say [copulate] here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I'd want this done as well, I doubt it's going to happen. We weren't even told what the damn thing was, let alone having a proper page explaining why it's there.

Let's just deal with it, unfortunately. The good thing would be that it also keeps spammers guessing as to what the hell that actually means.

Comment: Hmm, maybe spambots actually know more spam haikus than we do. And the text response is easily parsed for them.

Answer (score 3):

Just have the page link to [the **[haiku]** tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku) if they would like more info.

And have an extra can of spam on the page linked with the relevant Amazon affiliate encoded link.
(They sell tinned cans of spiced ham in Bezos' world don't they?)